# Gradient of picture to background

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a gradient of picture to background, kind of like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/yw9v7zm5/

but instead of the fade going from bottom to top, I would like it to go from right to left or vice versa.

even when I tried with:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
```

it didn't work!

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  linear gradient that starts from the Right and goes to left. Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yw9v7zm5/254/) fiddle.

Here is the changed css code.

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    padding:50px;
    margin:50px;
}
#contents {
   background:transparent
     }
#gradient {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 375px;
    width: 375px;
    background: none;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,255,.8) , rgba(226, 226, 226, 0));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );

}
```

You can learn more about css gradient in this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp).

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
<img src="Beautiful-White-Horse.jpg" style="-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))">
```

Please check this link:-https://webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/